Spin of local quantum fields in 2 + 1 dimensions
While reading Chapter 8 of Khare's textbook "Fractional Statistics And Quantum Theory", I came across this following statement

In fact it appears unlikely that one can
obtain a simple, local (relativistic) Lagrangian for anyons. This is because,
even in 2 + 1 dimensions, spin has to be integral or half-integral for local
fields.

I have never heard the last assertion before, and the textbook did not provide a reference for it. In higher dimensions, one can argue for this via the representation theory of the Poincare group, but in 2 + 1 dimensions the Poincare group allows for spin having an arbitrary real value. So, why is spin either integral or half-integral for local
fields even in 2 + 1 dimensions?

The author may have in mind that local fields, which are just some tensor fields $\phi_{\mu_1...\mu_s}(x)$, will have (half)-integer values of spin, which related to the number of indices and induced by the corresponding Lorentz transformation. Unless you start with such tensor fields you may have more options.
